# Find Max Value of Column Where Another Column is Greater Than X in Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, max, where-clause

With my data set below I am trying to find the max year where my amount is greater than 0 for each id after grouping my data.

```
df = df.groupby(['id','year']).sum().unstack().fillna(0).stack().sort(ascending=False)

print df

                     amount
id      year
1       2015             25
        2014              0
        2013              0
        2012              0
        2011              0
        2010              0
        2009              0
        2008              0
        2007            120
        2006            240
        2005            100
2       2015              0
        2014              0
        2013              0
        2012              0
        2011              0
        2010              0
        2009             25
        2008              0
        2007              0
        2006              0
        2005            100
3       2015              0
        2014              0
        2013              0
        2012              0
        2011              0
        2010              0
        2009              0
        2008              0
        2007              0
        2006              0
        2005              0
    ...                 ...
```

From the data I would like to indicate in some way, shape, or form that the following are the first years where the amount is greater than 0:

```
id   year       amount
1    2015       25
2    2009       25
3    None/Nan   None/Nan
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide a reproducible DataFrame, but does this work:

```
df.sort_values('year')
df[df['amount']> 0].iloc[:1]
```

Comment: This only returns the correct answer for one (the first) id. Is there a way to get the first year greater than zero for all of the ids?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use something like that:

```
np.where(amount > 0)
```

And after, you can make a selection like :

```
np.max()
```

I think that with Pandas you have command very similar